# What external pressure is required to burst a soap bubble with a radius of 4 cm?

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science, surface-tension

What external pressure is required to burst a soap bubble with a radius of 4 cm?

I'm looking to learn more about bubbles and I would really appreciate some help with this. So, I'm doing this practice problem. :)

I understand that you might require the surface tension variable. I'm still super new to this stuff.

Edit: Original title referred to atmospheric pressure, but I've since learned that this is a constant value that represents pressure at sea level.

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [Are check-my-work questions on-topic?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" problems.

Comment: @Yashas, correct. This isn't a homework problem, it's a practice problem that I created (poorly). I wasn't sure what tag to put :*( The appropriate tags have been added.

Comment: Changes in ambient air pressure will change the radius.   Popping requires a blemish of some sort in the soap film.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the atmospheric pressure is the cause of bubbles popping.
If you can blow a bubble in a given place then I don't think the atmosphere is the reason the bubble pops.
http://www.bubbles.org/html/questions/pop.htm is a good place to go for more information on what variables cause a bubble to burst.
I hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm glad I now know that the evaporation of water in dry air can lead to a bubble popping. The reason for this is that the water tension diminishes as the water evaporates, correct?

Is it also possible that outside atmospheric pressure can pop a bubble?

Comment: I believe they meant "what external pressure is required to burst the bubble".  Atmospheric pressure is generally a single standard value, the question doesn't really make sense asking "what atmospheric pressure" would cause something to fail.

Comment: @JMac, so a bubble that forms in an atmosphere with a pressure of 20 lb/in^2 wouldn't pop, as it would require more water tension? What about if a bubble was formed in an atmosphere with our pressure (~14.7 lb/in^2), then was magically teleported to another atmosphere with 1.5x the pressure?

Comment: @JasonProcka "Atmospheric pressure" generally refers to the standard atmospheric pressure at sea level of ~101 kPa.  It's usually used as a constant value.  A less ambiguous way to word it would be to talk about the internal and external pressures in the bubble.

Comment: @JMac, oh okay, I see! So what would that pressure be?

Comment: @JasonProcka I'm very new to this subject, but maybe looking at https://goo.gl/phA3pT will help you find an answer to your problem?